# JavaCV Image Processing error

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv, template-matching

I am working on a java project which includes match templates in images. I have seen some source codes, both have no errors about imports(I already have the javaCV libs),etc. but when I run it, it gives this error.

Here are the two source codes I have tried.

[MatchTemplate.java from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/obedrios/2625290)
[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292991/finding-image-in-specific-area-in-image-using-matching-template-in-javacv)

[image]

here it is to be clear.

OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -25 (Bad input roi) in cvInitImageHeader, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2918

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2918: error: (-25) Bad input roi in function cvInitImageHeader

```
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvCreateImage(Native Method)
at javacvtest.Test2.main(Test2.java:40)
```

Java Result: 1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when entering negative values into cvSize.  Make sure the template you are using is not bigger than the source image you are trying to match.  This could be the case if you created your template using something like ms paint.  I suggest you use a more suitable image editor like gimp.